# Time limit between buy and sell

Tags: ether, coinbase

Is there regulation and penalty on how long the period is between buying and selling Ethereum. Say I sell within a week of buying, then I have to pay much higher taxes and a penalty fee?

What is the minimum amount of time between buy and sell without incurring extra penalty?

I am using Coinbase by the way, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you at in the world? You're going to want to do research on capital gains if you're in the US. From https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Investments-and-Taxes/Guide-to-Short-term-vs-Long-term-Capital-Gains-Taxes--Brokerage-Accounts--etc--/INF22384.html

> **Short-term capital gains**
>
> Short-term capital gains do not benefit from any special tax rate –
>   they are taxed at the same rate as your ordinary income. For 2016,
>   ordinary tax rates range from 10 percent to 39.6 percent, depending on
>   your total taxable income.
>
> If you sell an asset you have held for one year or less, any profit
>   you make is considered a short-term capital gain. The clock begins
>   ticking from the day after you acquire the asset up to and including
>   the day you sell it.
>
> **Long-term capital gains**
>
> If you can manage to hold your assets for longer than a year, you can
>   benefit from a reduced tax rate on your profits. For 2016, the
>   long-term capital gains tax rates are 0, 15, and 20 percent for most
>   taxpayers. If your ordinary tax rate is already less than 15 percent,
>   you could qualify for the zero percent long-term capital gains rate.

If you're not buying and holding onto the asset for over a year, you need to treat all gains/losses as normal income when it comes time to do taxes.

Each state may have different tax laws as well.